# Delete only processed files from SFTP

Tags: linux, unix-sockets

We have 1000 files in SFTP server and are able to process in local server using linux script and it takes 10 mins, after processing we wants delete only processed files.
Mean time we my get some new files, we don't delete the files are arrived at the time of processing.

Please provide a solution for this.to write a script in Linux/unix.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the deleting *after* processing, here's what I would do in general terms: read the filenames into an array and then as they are processed add them to another array. Then at the end of your script you can loop over the array of processed filenames and then delete those files.

I would normally use a language that supports some kind of exception handling especially one with a keyword like `finally` so that you can save the array of processed files once the `finally` block is hit, either by reaching the end of the script in a normal way or if there is some kind of exception. This way you can restart from where you left off.

A simpler approach would be to delete the file just after you process it.

Comment: A simpler approach would be to delete the file just after you process it.    What could be the command to delete the file just after you process it???   pls

Comment: @venkatakrishna The command you're thinking of is probably `rm filename`

Comment: If you want to do the deleting after processing, here's what I would do in general terms: read the filenames into an array and then as they are processed add them to another array. Then at the end of your script you can loop over the array of processed filenames and then delete those files.---------->> Please provide some example command for above approach

Comment: Extract the files as of 2AM and delete all the files from source which are before 2AM cutoff using a last run file or table to hold the timestamp--->> Please provide command for this seniro

Comment: @venkatakrishna you'll need to let me know which language you're working in. If it's Bash, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981499/200908

Comment: We have 1000 files in SFTP server and are able to process in local server using linux script and it takes 10 mins, after processing we wants delete only processed files. Mean time we my get some new files, we don't delete the files are arrived at the time of processing.